# write functions langage C

Tags: c, file

Hi i'm trying to write into a file using the write function.But i got '^^' instead of my variable :
below my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

main (int argc,char * argv[])
{
    FILE *PF=NULL;
    char File_name_1[100];
    int fd=0;
    char str[30] = "This is test";
    int var=30;         

    printf("Saisir le nom du fichier2 ");
    scanf("%s",File_name_1);

    if ( (fd = open(File_name_1,O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT,0777)) < 0 )
    {
            printf("Impossible d'ouvrir fichier \n");
    }
    else
    {       printf("Traitement2 à commencer2 var :%d:",var);
            write(fd,&var,sizeof(var));
    }

    close(fd);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using hex editor or `od -Ax -t x1 filename` command to check the content of the file.

Comment: By the way, what is your question?

Comment: Hi,i retrieve this result : 0000000  00 00 00 1e
0000004 after using the command od -Ax -t x1 y.I should retrieve 30 in my file.

Comment: 0x1e = 16+14  = 30, so it seems correct and your machine seems using big endian.

Comment: Try `od -Ax -t d4 y.l` or `od -Ax -t d1 y.l`.

Comment: I retrieve 0000000           30
0000004.But why i didn't retrieve the valeur 30 in my file.Because when i used :    char str[30] = "This is test";
write(fd,&str,sizeof(str));i retrieve in my file : This is test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here :

```
write(fd,&var,sizeof(var));
```

You are trying to write an int into your file. The second parameter of write should be of type char * if you want to write something readable for a human. Try to use the itoa function to convert your var value, it will transform it into a string representation of that number. If itoa is not available on your system, you can also use sprintf :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <strings.h> //for strlen

    int main (int argc,char * argv[])
    {
    char buff[256]; //the buffer used by sprintf
    char File_name_1[100];
    int fd=0;
    char str[30] = "This is test";
    int var=30;         

    printf("Saisir le nom du fichier2 ");
    scanf("%s",File_name_1);

    if ( (fd = open(File_name_1,O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT,0777)) < 0 )
    {
            printf("Impossible d'ouvrir fichier \n");
    }
    else
    {       printf("Traitement2 à commencer2 var :%d:",var);
            sprintf(buff, "%d", var); //convert your int into a string
            write(fd,buff,strlen(buff)); //wrtie the string in the fd
    }

    close(fd);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi,I tried to add the itoa function to convert the integer to the string but i received this error once i compile:ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .itoa
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.

Comment: I edited my answer. I forgot that itoa is not always available on Linux systems. Here is a sprintf example.